# What's the difference between "obwohl" and "trotz" grammatically?

Tags: difference, word-order

What’s the difference between *obwohl* and *trotz* grammatically?

Does the verb goes to the end of the sentence when we use *trotz*?

Comment: Could you give an example? "Trotz" does not introduce a relative clause.

Comment: " ........ traf die Polizei schon wenige Minuten nach dem Überfall ein, von den Tätern aber fehlt jede Spur." What do we use in this sentence, "Obwohl" or "Trotz" .

Comment: Both would be ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The greatest difference between both is that **trotz** initiates a genitive while **obwohl** does not.

> Wir gingen spazieren, trotz des schlechten Wetters.
>
> Wir gingen spazieren, obwohl das Wetter schlecht war.

That also means that you do not use a verb when using **trotz**. It is important to notice that you would not use a sentence order like this when using **trotz**. It is more likely to put the **trotz** subordinate clause before the main clause:

> Trotz des schlechten Wetters gingen wir spazieren.

Why you don’t need a verb there? Because the sentences has a genitive object which replaces a complete

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] for any remaining questions about it you may have.

Comment: The even more fundamental difference is that _trotz_ is a preposition and _obwohl_ a conjunction. There is so such thing as a “_trotz_ subordinate clause”.

Answer (score 5):

*Obwohl* introduces a subordinate clause:

> Er ging einkaufen, obwohl es regnete.
>
> Obwohl es regnete, ging er einkaufen.

*Trotz* is a preposition:

> Trotz des Regens ging er einkaufen.
>
> Er ging trotz des Regens einkaufen.